# Select records with max value for some date

Tags: sql

I have following table:

[image]

I need select players max scores for all players in some date.

For instance I need highest scores which players achieved after 2000-1-1:
expected result:

[image]

I tried following select:

```
select *
from player_score ps
where ps.created_at >= '2000-1-1' 
and ps.score = (select max(ps2.score) 
                  from player_score ps2 
                  where ps2.player_id = ps.player_id)
```

but it returns me just one record:

[image]

Can you tell me please what is the best way to achieve my expected result? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by max scores?  There is only one player who scores max after 2000-1-1.

Comment: @Aoi pick bigger one. If player with id has in year 2000 score 20 an 30, I should record with score 30

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff postgres, but I would like have universal query if it possible

Answer (score 1):

Since you want per player `max`, do a `group by player_id`

```
select ps.player_id, max(ps.score)
from player_score ps
where ps.created_at >= '2000-1-1' group by ps.player_id
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I need just pure records with their columns. I cannot show in query max value

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by date in the subquery as well:

```
select ps.*
from player_score ps
where ps.created_at >= '2000-01-01' 
and ps.score = (select max(ps2.score) 
                from player_score ps2 
                where ps2.created_at >= '2000-01-01' and
                      ps2.player_id = ps.player_id
               );
```

The overall maximum occurred before the cutoff date for other players, which is why there are no rows.

If you arbitrarily want one record per player, even when there are ties for the highest score, then compare ids rather than scores:

```
select ps.*
from player_score ps
where ps.created_at >= '2000-01-01' 
and ps.id = (select ps2.id 
             from player_score ps2 
             where ps2.created_at >= '2000-01-01' and
                   ps2.player_id = ps.player_id
             order by ps2.score desc
             limit 1
            );
```

In Postgres, the simplest solution is:

```
select distinct on (player_id) ps.*
from player_score ps
where ps.created_at >= '2000-01-01' 
order by player_id, score desc;
```

Comment: Hi, this query works until I have 2 records with same score :/ distinct doesn't works

Comment: @DenisStephanov . . . I don't understand the comment.  Do you mean two records for the same player?

Comment: Yes, when I add next record for player with id 4, score 0 as well it returns not unique records. For player 4 I got 2 records with same values.

Comment: Second solution give me error: ore than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: @DenisStephanov . . . It needed the `limit 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution by Gordon Linoff, you can also solve it using the `IN` predicate.
But make sure to put the `GROUP BY` clause inside the subquery rather than the outer query.

```
SELECT  id, 
        player_id,
        score,
        created_at 
FROM player_score ps2
WHERE ps2.score IN (SELECT MAX(score) FROM player_score ps
            WHERE created_at >= '2000-1-1'  AND ps.player_id = ps2.player_id
            GROUP BY ps.player_id)
ORDER BY player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

the maximum is always one value so if you need more value us "ORDER BY DESC"
and it will return you all values with descending order upper to lower and you can see the maximum values at top of the table

Answer (score 0):

Respecting to @krithikaGopalakrisnan's answer, assuming you need the ID and CreatedDate columns in the result set, you can use:

```
;with cte (player_id,MaxScore) as (
   select ps.player_id, max(ps.score) as MaxScore
   from player_score ps
   where ps.created_at >= '2000-1-1' 
   group by ps.player_id
)
select ps.*
from player_score ps
inner join cte on cte.player_id = ps.player_id and cte.MaxScore = ps.Score
where ps.created_at >= '2000-1-1'
```